# moving from hibernate to openjpa: Errors encountered while resolving metadata

Tags: hibernate, persistence, openjpa

I am working in a project which used hibernate and is my job to switch it to openjpa (because it is going to be integrated to another bigger project which already uses openjpa).

now, when running my tests I am getting an error saying:

```
eu.ist_phosphorus.harmony.idb.exceptions.database.DatabaseException: Errors encountered while resolving metadata.  See nested exceptions for details.
...
...
at eu.ist_phosphorus.harmony.idb.database.hibernate.Domain.save(Domain.java:878)
at
eu.ist_phosphorus.harmony.idb.database.hibernate.Domain$4.dbOperation(Domain.java:885)
at
eu.ist_phosphorus.harmony.idb.database.TransactionManager.start(TransactionManager.java:108)
... 30 more
...
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Errors encountered while resolving metadata.  See nested exceptions for details.
FailedObject: eu.ist_phosphorus.harmony.idb.database.hibernate.Domain@17bf9b45 [java.lang.String]
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolve(MetaDataRepository.java:668)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaDataInternal(MetaDataRepository.java:411)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:384)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AttachManager.attach(AttachManager.java:248)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AttachManager.attach(AttachManager.java:105)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.attach(BrokerImpl.java:3474)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.attach(DelegatingBroker.java:1214)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.merge(EntityManagerImpl.java:878)
at eu.ist_phosphorus.harmony.idb.database.hibernate.Domain.save(Domain.java:878)
at eu.ist_phosphorus.harmony.idb.database.hibernate.Domain$4.dbOperation(Domain.java:885)
at eu.ist_phosphorus.harmony.idb.database.TransactionManager.start(TransactionManager.java:108)
... 30 more
 Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "eu.ist_phosphorus.harmony.idb.database.hibernate.Domain.endpoints<key:class java.lang.Object>" declared that it is mapped by "TNA", but that is a not a field of the related type.
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.ValueMetaDataImpl.getValueMappedByMetaData(ValueMetaDataImpl.java:329)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ValueMappingImpl.getValueMappedByMapping(ValueMappingImpl.java:121)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ValueMappingImpl.getColumns(ValueMappingImpl.java:130)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ValueMappingImpl.resolveMapping(ValueMappingImpl.java:518)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ValueMappingImpl.resolve(ValueMappingImpl.java:500)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.resolveMapping(FieldMapping.java:522)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.resolve(FieldMapping.java:461)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ClassMapping.resolveMapping(ClassMapping.java:854)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.ClassMetaData.resolve(ClassMetaData.java:1802)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.processBuffer(MetaDataRepository.java:822)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolveMapping(MetaDataRepository.java:777)
at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolve(MetaDataRepository.java:657)
... 40 more
```

The error is being triggered by a EntityManager.merge() that previously was SessionManager.saverOrUpdate(). I know these methods work a bit different, but by the error it doesnt seem to be a problem persisting, but something before that.

I didnt touch the entities much when moving from hibernate to openjpa, I removed some @Proxy(lazy = false) annotations and change the criteria api calls.

Mapping for one side:

```
@Id
public String getTNA() {
    return this.TNA;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fkDomainName")
public Domain getDomain() {
    return this.domain;
}
```

and the mapping for the other side:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "domain", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { javax.persistence.CascadeType.REMOVE })
@MapKey(name = "TNA")
public Set<Endpoint> getEndpoints() {
    return this.endpoints;
}
```

update- I have change the entityManager.merge() for a persist() but I still have the same issues

I also noticed that the set is  not . could this have caused the issue while moving to openjpa?

Comment: Can you post the annotations for eu.ist_phosphorus.harmony.idb.database.hibernate.Domain.endpoints?

Comment: hi Rick. I added the mapping for the endpoints.

Comment: Can you also post Endpoint.domain?

Comment: Try removing @MapKey, I'm not sure why that is there?

Comment: it was working like that when the project was using hibernate. Being a jpa annotation should its behavior be the same across jpa providers?

Comment: btw. that works. would you mind putting it as an answer so I can select it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing @MapKey. I think it is incorrect to use it in this context.

> The @MapKey annotation is used to specify the map key for associations of type java.util.Map
>   when the map key is itself the primary key or a persistent field or property of the entity that is the value of the map.